# How to export GraphicsRow with anti-aliasing?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

When I put two objects below inside GraphicsRow, it seems to turn off their antialiasing. Can anyone see some way to Export graphics row in example below with antialiasing?

[image]
<sub>(source: [yaroslavvb.com](http://yaroslavvb.com/upload/save/so-aliased.png))</sub>

I tried various combination of `Style[#,Antialiasing->True]` and Preferences with no luck.
The closest work-around I is to `Rasterize` them at 4 times the resolution, but that has a side effect of changing appearance of objects with `AbsoluteThickness`, for instance, Box around each object becomes faded out.

```
picA = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], 
    GraphicsComplex[{{-1., 0., 0.}, {0., -1., 0.}, {0., 0., -1.}, {0.,
        0., 1.}, {0., 1., 0.}, {1., 0., 
       0.}}, {{{EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.]], 
        GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[{{4, 5, 1}, {1, 5, 3}, {1, 3, 2}, {4, 
             1, 2}, {3, 5, 6}, {5, 4, 6}, {4, 2, 6}, {2, 3, 
             6}}]}]}, {}, {}, {}, {}}}]}];
picB = Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], 
    GraphicsComplex[{{-1., 0., 0.}, {-0.5, -0.8660254037844386, 
       0.}, {-0.5, 0.8660254037844386, 1.}, {0., 
       0., -1.}, {0.5, -0.8660254037844386, 1.}, {0.5, 
       0.8660254037844386, 0.}, {1., 0., 
       0.}}, {{{EdgeForm[GrayLevel[0.]], 
        GraphicsGroup[{Polygon[{{6, 7, 4}, {2, 1, 4}}], 
          Polygon[{{1, 2, 5, 3}, {6, 3, 5, 7}, {5, 2, 4, 7}, {3, 6, 4,
              1}}]}]}, {}, {}, {}, {}}}]}];
GraphicsRow[{picA, picB}]
```

Comment: From the help .. _For 3D graphics, the operation of Antialiasing can depend on the particular graphics hardware you are using.  Antialiasing is disabled unless Allow Antialiasing is set in the Preferences dialog._ So perhaps there is some hardware issue. In my poor's man machine Antialiasing doesn't work at all for Graphics3D

Comment: Ah, that explains why I get better quality antialiasing if I rasterize at higher resolution rather than using default Graphics3D look...I probably shouldn't use default antialiasing at all

Comment: You are not missing much, video-card anti-aliasing doesn't look very good anyway, better use Rasterize --  http://mathematica-bits.blogspot.com/2010/12/making-anti-aliased-diagrams.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just a quick comment: have you enabled anti-aliasing in the Preferences dialog?

Comment: Well, I'll consider this question resolved since it's better to use Rasterize to get antialiasing, and the problem doesn't happen there